# Goでネットからダウンロードした画像をデコードできない

Tags: go

Go言語で画像をダウンロードし、それを扱うためにImage構造体に変換するコードを作成したのですが、以下のエラーのためできませんでした。

```
func getImage(url string) (image.Image, []byte, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)

    img, _, err := image.Decode(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return img, data, nil
}
```

**エラー**

```
image: unknown format
```

これは上記コードの`image.Decode`で起きています。

今年の4月までは上記コードが動いていたのですが、今動かしたところエラーが出ました。Goのバージョンの違いだと思いますが、どのように修正すれば動くようにできるのでしょうか。

`image/jpeg`と`image/png`はインポートできています。

**問題を再現可能なコード**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    doneCh := make(chan bool, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go getImage("http://safebooru.org/images/1715/d55b7029064f477ab3838c71456010896444d851.jpg", doneCh)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        <-doneCh
    }
}

func getImage(url string, doneCh chan bool) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("http.Get failed", err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatal("StatusCode is not 200", resp.StatusCode)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ioutil.ReadAll failed", err)
    }
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    img, _, err := image.Decode(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("image.Decode failed", err)
    }
    _ = img
    log.Printf("OK: Bounds=%+v\n", img.Bounds())

    doneCh <- true

}
```

Comment: (※ 回答は削除しました)  ダウンロードした画像ファイルが JPEG や PNG 以外のフォーマットなのではないでしょうか。

Comment: resp.StatusCode には 200 が返ってきてますか? 実は 304 とかで飛ばされてて Body が空とか、サーバーが何かのエラーで 500 を返しているとかの可能性もあります。

Comment: @metropolis さんテスト画像の1枚目の画像のリンクが切れていました。

Comment: @KoRoN さん おっしゃるとおり304でした。http://safebooru.org/images/1715/d55b7029064f477ab3838c71456010896444d851.jpg この画像なんですが、ダウンロードできないのでしょうか。

Comment: やっぱりできません。。。。。。。。

Comment: 私の手元では https://play.golang.org/p/mwZ_0G-nu6 このプログラムが実行に成功して、 `2016/07/05 23:28:15 OK: Bounds=(0,0)-(900,1270)` のように画像のサイズを取得できています。

Comment: このコード自体ではなくこの関数を並列実行していたため503エラーが出ていたようです。

Comment: i=8までは503エラーが出ませんでした。

Comment: `503(Service Unavailable)`なので、同じ IP アドレスから同じ画像ファイルに対する(ほぼ)同時の並列アクセスがサーバで過負荷と判断されたのではないでしょうか。上記のプログラムを順次アクセスに変更すると `i=10` でもエラーにはなりません。

Comment: どうやらそのようです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

要望:**不要な部分をなくして必要なコードを付与した問題を再現可能なコード**を質問に書いてください。

一応以下のコードで動作することは確認できました。

https://play.golang.org/p/NTWLnceZlj

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func getImage(url string) (image.Image, []byte, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)

    img, _, err := image.Decode(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return img, data, nil
}

func main() {
    img, data, err := getImage("http://safebooru.org/images/1715/d55b7029064f477ab3838c71456010896444d851.jpg")
    fmt.Println(img)
    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

これで動きます。

Comment: 問題を再現可能なコードを追記しました。